# Is "T var();" always a function declaration in c++?

Tags: c++, syntax

Can that be an instantiation(definition) on certain cases?

Answer (score 3):

It's always a function declaration in C++ (and in C), except when it appears as a parameter declaration, in which case it declares a function pointer.

The inverse can't be stated though:

> Is "T var;" always an object declaration in C++?

No it isn't, because `T` can be a function type, in which case `var` will be declared as a function, except when it appears as a parameter declaration, as above.

Comment: @lex: when parentheses are no empty then it obviously depends what is in them. '1' does not look like parameter declaration but like an int argument for T constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> Is `“T var();”` always a function declaration in c++?

Depends on the context.

Context 1:

```
template<typename T> 
void func()
{
    T var(); // function declaration
}
```

Context 2:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T var() ) // equivalent to `template<typename T> void func (T()) { } `
{
}
```

In this case `func` returns void and takes as an argument a pointer to a function returning `T`. Omitting `var` is optional.

---

> What about `T var(1)`;,is it instantiation or is it the same as `T var = T(1)`;

`T var(1)` is *direct initialization* whereas `T var = T(1)` is *copy initialization*. In both the cases an object `var` is initialized to T(`1`).

If `T` is a user defined type the latter case requires an *accessible* copy constructor whereas the former doesn't.

Comment: What about `T var(1);`,is it instantiation or is it the same as `T var = T(1);`?

Comment: So why `T var()` can't be regarded as direct initialization?

Comment: @lex : Because that how the parsing rules (grammar) of C++ are defined.

Comment: So direct initialization only applies for constructors with parameters?

Comment: Nopes. `int a(1)` is also perfectly valid.